# About high-symmetry points in the first Brillouin zone of space group R-3m

Tags: band-structure, symmetry, k-points, space-groups, brillouin-zone

I want to figure out the high-symmetry points in the first Brillouin zone of space group R-3m (166). For example, there are points K and M just like the bandstructure in [this paper](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/2516-1075/acd28d).
But I can't figure out each component of kx, ky, kz from [Bilbao Crystallographic Serve](https://www.cryst.ehu.es/cgi-bin/cryst/programs/nph-kv-list).
Can anyone help me? I am not fimiliar about space groups. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This paper - [High-throughput electronic band structure calculations: Challenges and tools](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0927025610002697) - lists the high-symmetry points and the suggested k-path for band structure plots for all the Bravais crystals.

Answer (score 5):

As described on the [paper](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/2516-1075/acd28d/pdf), the system presents a hexagonal unit cell. From the paper recommended by @MathJacky (if you don't have access to the published paper, there is an [arXiv version](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1004.2974.pdf)), we have that the Brillouin zone lattice is:

[image]

And the high symmetry points $\Gamma$, $A$, $H$, $K$, $L$, and $M$ can be calculated as:

[image]

With that information, you can generate the path between continuous points.